# Bamboo java specs get default branch name

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs, bamboo-artifacts

I want to set artifactBaranch for auto deployment in bamboo but before that I would like check if that branch is default or not. If that branch is default then I will not set the artifact branch name.

So my question is, is there any way to get default git branch name in bamboo specs using java?

Answer (score 2):

See RssRuntimeContext utility class https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/latest/specs.html?java#java-specs-utilities

Comment: That's a handy trick. Any idea what `RSS` stands for btw?

Comment: RSS is Repository Stored Specs